# How to export asset at different densities for Android platform (mdpi hdpi xhdpi xxhdpi xxhdpi)

Tags: sketch-app, android

I am exporting image for Android as per title, and read somewhere that one can start at a base density, then just scale the asset and export as PNGs following this formula

```
mdpi = ~160dpi = 1×, or 100%
hdpi = ~240dpi = 1.5×, or 150%
xhdpi = ~320dpi = 2×, or 200%
xxhdpi = ~480dpi = 3×, or 300%
xxxhdpi = ~640dpi = 4×, or 400%
```

anyone here that has done this that can confirm or elucidate?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood from the question;

You can find the presets near the make exportable section. Please follow the images.

[image: Select the adjustments icon to see presets]
[image: Select the Android preset from the list]
[image: Android sizes]

You can edit the preset or add new presets in sketch preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for me has been to scale the assets in Sketch with respect to an mdpi device resolution as baseline, then manually create the density bucket folders in /res/drawables then add the assets.